# Xamarin Forms - Sending multiple images to filestream with MediaGallery plugin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, stream

I'm working on an Xamarin Forms application and I have added some code to select multiple images from the phone gallery, I then need to send all selected images to file steam.

Selecting multiple images from the gallery is working fine, but only the last selected image is being sent.

Below is my code

```
private async Task OnGetExistingPhotoAsync() {
  try {
    // Selecting multiple images with the MediaGallery plugin

    var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(3, MediaFileType.Image);
    var parameter = new NavigationParameters();

    if (results?.Files == null) {
      return;
    }

    foreach(var photo in results.Files) {
      if (photo == null) {
        PhotoPath = null;
        return;
      }

      string newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.NameWithoutExtension);
      using(var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
      using(var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
      await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
      PhotoPath = newFile;

      // This here is only sending the PATH of the last selected image from the gallery
      parameter.Add("PhotoPath", PhotoPath);


      // In my attempt here, I tried to add each image PATH to a list Array
      // But this is not working!
      /*
      List<string> imageFiles = new List<string>();
      imageFiles.Add(Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.NameWithoutExtension));

      String[] newFile = imageFiles.ToArray();

      using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
      using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile)) // This here says that it cannot convert ( string[] to string )
          await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

      parameter.Add("PhotoPath", PhotoPath);
      */

    }

    //OUTPUT :  The PATH is : /data/user/0/se.company.trret.cyn/cache/IMG_20220307_005342
    Console.WriteLine("The PATH is : " + PhotoPath);

    await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameter);
  } catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx) {
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ett fel inträffade", "Den här funktionen stöds inte av din enhet.", "Ok");
  } catch (PermissionException pEx) {
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ett fel inträffade", "Cykelstaden saknar rättigheter för att läsa dina filer.", "Ok");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ett fel inträffade", "Ett oväntat fel inträffade. Var god försök igen.", "Ok");
    Crashes.TrackError(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: `to send all selected images to file steam.` Sorry, what does that mean?  You have ONE file stream? What is a file stream? And you want to send all images to ONE stream? Where should that land?

Comment: The code I'm working on was not written by me orignally, there was another developer before me and I have no contact with him. 

As you can see in the code `parameter.Add("PhotoPath", PhotoPath);` only one photo path is saved. I just need to save the PATH of all images in the for each loop and add them to `parameter.Add("PhotoPath", PhotoPath);`

Comment: `only one photo path is saved.` You mean: is added to the list? And how often? It's called for every file isn't it? A path? or only a file name? I wonder why you did not put a bunch of logstatements in that code. You would be able to better follow what is happening.

Comment: With the MediaGallery plugin I'm able to select multiple images, but only the PATH of the last selected image is saved in memory or whatever it is, so the for each loop is not working properly.

Comment: I cannot folloiw you. What would be saved in memory? And by who? If the user picks five files then how many files in the foreach loop?

Comment: you are initializing `imageFiles` **inside the loop**, so it is being reset on each iteration of the loop.  This initialization needs to be done **outside the loop**.  This a very basic programming logic problem

Comment: I will try fixing this ASAP, if that fixes the problem then I'm an idiot

Comment: Good catch @Jason. And `Console.WriteLine("The PATH is : " + PhotoPath);` that should be inside the loop. And .. declare PhotoPath inside the loop as you dont need it outside. Well you should not.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake